# XSLT stylesheet modification to get some tags that are gone after the transformation

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I transform some RSS XML feeds using XSLT. Basically there are two types I edit :

```
1. <rss><channel>some tags about the RSS<item></item></channel></rss>
2. <feed>some tags about the RSS<entry></entry></feed>
```

using this stylesheet. (It gets some files from a paths.xml file)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <NEWrss>
        <xsl:for-each select="file">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="document(.)/*//channel | document(.)/f:feed/f:entry">
                <xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </NEWrss>
</xsl:template>
```

On the first RSS I get correctly the output with the tags between `<channel>` and first `<item>`. Those are some tags that contain info about the blog, like the title.

However, on the second, those tags (title of the blog... found between the `<feed>` and first `<entry>`) are gone after the transformation. The tags in  appeared correctly.

My question is how can I get those tags too ?

A sample Feed like the 2nd structure is http://feeds.feedburner.com/EFENPRESS-

Thank you.

Comment: So, what is each of the source XML documents and what is the exact output result wanted? Everything else is just noise ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're saying is you don't see the text preceding the f:feed element.  That's because your select statement doesn't include it - it only selects f:feed/f:entry and channel elements.  Maybe you should try processing f:feed instead of f:feed/f:entry?  or f:feed/node(), which will select both f:feed/text() and f:feed()/f:entry.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a namespace issue. You're using a namespace prefix "f" to access the feed and entry elements, but it's not apparent that those elements are really in that namespace. (And actually, the entry element is empty, so accessing that will not render any content)

Comment: You mention the "first entry", which suggests you think there are several entry elements. There's only one. Its opening tag is <entry>, its closing tag is </entry>, and its content is everything in between (i.e., nothing).

Comment: I get all the contents between `<entry></entry>` I do not get the tags between `<feed>` and first `<entry>`